# Convert a date and time into a MS SQL select query using SelectParameters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, formatting

I have this situation where I have a SqlDatasource control and the select query is like:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE colDate = @date
```

The source of @date is a label with the text: 2009-05-29 12:06:00
I get the following error when I run the query:

> Conversion failed when converting date
>   and/or time from character string

I tried using convert(datetime, @date), as well as different date/time formatting of the label itself. Everytime I get the error.

However, when I run the query in the management studio like:

```
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE colDate = '2009-05-29 12:06:00'
```

it works like a charm!

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

EDIT:

I found out that the @date is parsed as 05-29-2009 01:30:00 TT 
I don't know where the TT is coming from? And I'm sure SQL Server wouldn't be able to handle it?

Comment: how are you intializing the @date parameter?

Comment: I added the following to the SqlDatasource:

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="label1" Name="date" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE colDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @date, 120)
```

And try:

```
<SelectParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="label1" Name="date" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: That does work in the management studio but not in the SQLdatasource.SelectCommand :( I think it's got to do with how the @date parameter is parsed...

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE colDate = convert(datetime, @date,120)
```

For a complete listing of the available conversion formats with respect to the datetime data type, please refer to the following SQL Server Books Online Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, I had a Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT") which added the double T's to the @date... Runs perfectly now!

Thanks all!